# Как при запуске скрипта Jenkinsfile через скрипт обратиться к другим файлам?

Tags: jenkins

В Jenkins настроен репозиторий, в котором лежит Jenkinsfile со скриптом.
Когда скрипт доходит до определенного момента есть необходимость обратиться к другому файлу который лежит в том же репозитории git. Не понимаю как это сделать.
sh 'ls' показывает пустую папку, хотя я думал, что репозиторий клонируется перед запуском Jenkinsfile скрипта

Comment: клонируется на master-е. а директива `sh` у вас явно на node в её workspace выполняется. где никакого репозитория, естественно, нет. используйте директиву `git` для клонирования.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в конструкции Jenkinfile.
Как только скачивался и запускался скрипт там выполнялась команда CleanWS, которая очищала всё, что скачалось, после её удаления всё заработало.